# Applying for a UK Settlement Visa from Italy with an expired Permesso di Soggiorno

Tags: uk, italy

I intend on applying for the UK-Spouse visa from Italy. Currently my Italian Residence Permit has expired and I ahve applied for its renewal which would take some months. In the meantime I have the Post Office receipt with me as a proof that I'm currently legally resident in Italy and have a renewal in process. Based on these circumstances, am I eligible to apply for the UK Visa at their centre in Rome?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I eligible to apply for the UK Visa at their centre in Rome?

Yes.  The UK is less strict about residence for visa applicants than are the Schengen countries.  Anyway, you are applying in your place of residence and you have documents showing that your presence is legal.